# Why doesn't Scala's Future have a .get / get(maxDuration) method, forcing us to resort to Await.result() instead?

Tags: scala, future

Is there any particular advantage in decoupling the `get` method from the `Future` class (where I'd expect it to reside) and to instead force the coder to have to know about this external two-method class called `Await`?

Comment: Every future in scala stdlib has a .get by default.

Comment: @Andreas [Do they](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future)? Where is it defined?

Comment: see my answer further down

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there any particular advantage in decoupling the `get` method from the `Future` class

Yes, to make it difficult for the developer to do *the wrong thing*. A `Future` represents a computation which will complete in the future and might not be available at the current invocation point. If you need to block a future, why not execute it synchronously? Whats the point of scheduling it on the threadpool, wasting a perfectly good threadpool thread?

The [documentation says](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html):

> ### Blocking outside the Future
>
> As mentioned earlier, blocking on a future is strongly discouraged for the sake of performance and for the prevention of deadlocks. Callbacks and combinators on futures are a preferred way to use their results. However, blocking may be necessary in certain situations and is supported by the Futures and Promises API.

And even the [`Await` object documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$):

> While occasionally useful, e.g. for testing, it is recommended that you avoid Await when possible in favor of callbacks and combinators like onComplete and use in for comprehensions. Await will block the thread on which it runs, and could cause performance and deadlock issues.

You can see that the language designers intentionally wanted this effect.

Answer (score 16):

To provide a bit more history<sup>1</sup> on the accepted answer:

When we sat out to formalize the plethora of Future implementations in the Scala ecosystem, we wanted to make sure<sup>2</sup> we didn't standardize methods which were known to create problems.

> A `Future` represents a value (or the inability to produce said value)
>   divorced from time.

More concretely means that `Future[T]` has strictly less information that a simple `T` as illustrated by:

```
//At the line of this comment, there is no `f`
val f: Future[T] = … //At the line of this comment, there is an `f` but not necessarily its value of type `T`.
```

Whereas:

```
//At the line of this comment, there is no `t`
val t: T = … //At the line of this comment, there is a `T`
```

Why is this important, I hear you say.
Well, if you want to have a method from `Future[T]` to `T`, you are saying: I receive a value which may not be available, and I will return after it is.

This means that the method will have to »pass time« while the value is not yet available, this typically entails *blocking* the current thread of execution, and since threads of execution is an expensive resource and it typically takes time to go into a blocked state and come back out again<sup>3</sup>, this is to be avoided.

As if that wasn't enough, it is very easy to get into deadlocks where Futures could not complete since they wouldn't get a Thread to execute on, because all those threads were stuck trying to *get* that Future's value.

Furthermore, we realized that whenever a Future implementation had a «blocking get» operation, many users would invoke it without realizing what effect it would have on their programs until it created problems in production, since it is deceptively simple to call, but its cost is nowhere to be seen until too late.

So we decided to promote the programming style which doesn't require blocking, such as callbacks<sup>4</sup> and transformations<sup>5</sup> to reduce risk of deadlocks and poor performance.

We figured that if we were to completely omit the capability to block to get a result from a Future, the end result would be that everyone would reinvent it, and possibly with varying quality.

We also found that if we made the capability of waiting a concrete [thing](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.concurrent.Awaitable) we got the following benefits:

- The API looks the same for all `Awaitable`s
- It's easy to code review for/against
- It's easy to forbid/allow, using tooling
- We can hook into the notion of [`blocking`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.concurrent.BlockContext) to try to perform evasive actions to mitigate deadlocks, *forbid* it at runtime, log it, time it, etc.

So there you have it!

Cheers,
√

<sup>1</sup> Being a co-creator of SIP-14 "Futures and Promises" and maintainer of it since.

<sup>2</sup> As sure as you can ever be when it comes to APIs…

<sup>3</sup> Thread wakeup lag can effectively limit processing to between 1k-10kops/s.

<sup>4</sup> We are also increasingly de-emphasizing the use of callbacks, instead promoting to the use of transformation combinators, see [this](https://github.com/viktorklang/blog/blob/master/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-1.md) blog series I wrote for Scala 2.12 Futures.

<sup>5</sup> Ex. `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `recover`, `recoverWith`, and more recently `transform` and `transformWith`

Comment: Priceless. Thanks for the overview Viktor.

Comment: Thank you, Yuval! Thanks for your great answer!

Answer (score 2):

## get on Futures

There is a `.get` on Futures provided since the first implementation in the Scala standard lib.
It is somewhat hidden though: `.value.get`

```
scala> val f = Future("test")
f: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = Success(test)

scala> f.value.get
res5: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(test)
```

The downside of using this though is that it will throw an exception if the future has not yet returned.

```
scala> Future("test").value.get
res7: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(test)

scala> Future("test").value.get
 java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
 at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
 at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
 ... 32 elided
```

## Why `Await.result` and not `get(timeToWait)` ?

Adding to @YuvalsItzchakov's excellent answer:
The idea of using `Future` i to make the asynchronicity visible in to the type system and all coders showing that using this concept special rules apply and caution needs to be taken.
As it is an Applicative Functor you have a really is and straightforward way to work with the values by using `map` or `foreach` and also the means to chain them with `map` and `flatMap`.

The only thing which is by intention not builtin is how to "unfuture" a `Future` while keeping special time dependant configurable waiting rules in place.
This would roughly describe what `Await.result` would do.

Comment: It's important to note that `.value` is a `Option[Try[T]]`, not the actual underlying `T`, so it doesn't really provide the blocking semantics the OP is expecting.