# Why Scala forces uses of Await instead of Awaitable?

Tags: scala

[`Awaitable` trait](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/ba9701059216c629410f4f23a2175d20ad62484b/src/library/scala/concurrent/Awaitable.scala#L29) requires `CanAwait` implicit which couldn't be used outside of [concurrent](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/ba9701059216c629410f4f23a2175d20ad62484b/src/library/scala/concurrent/package.scala#L134) package. So, you are technically not allowed to call `Awaitable` methods directly and should use `Await` object instead.

I want to understand why such a design decision was made.

```scala
trait Awaitable[+T] {
  def ready(atMost: Duration)(implicit permit: CanAwait): this.type
}

package concurrent {
  sealed trait CanAwait
  private[concurrent] object AwaitPermission extends CanAwait 

  object Await {
    def ready[T](awaitable: Awaitable[T], atMost: Duration): awaitable.type =
      blocking(awaitable.ready(atMost)(AwaitPermission))
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155159/why-doesnt-scalas-future-have-a-get-getmaxduration-method-forcing-us-to is close enough to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

Because they don't what you to be able to override `Awaitable.ready` in your own classes. 
They could make it `private[concurrent]`, but then you would not be able to call it either. They could also make it `final`, but then overriding it in subclasses would not be possible (of which there is only one, so, it's not really a problem in this case ... but what if they wanted to add more later?)

Comment: Awaitable.ready is abstract method. So it is intended to be overridden